# The package system is broken: can not update or install new packages

Tags: package-management, dependencies

I am not new to Ubuntu, but I don"t know what to do with the following:

```
sudo apt-get -o Debug::pkgProblemResolver=yes dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libqt4-declarative : Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed
 libqt4-designer : Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed
 libqt4-help : Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed
 libqt4-opengl : Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed
 libqt4-qt3support : Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed
 libqt4-scripttools : Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed
 libqt4-svg : Depends: libqtgui4 (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed
 libqtgui4 : Depends: libqt4-declarative (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
             Depends: libqtcore4 (= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
             Breaks: libqtgui4:i386 (!= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
 libqtgui4:i386 : Breaks: libqtgui4 (!= 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1) but 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I cannot update or install any packages. Please help, what I should do..

I tried also this:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libqtgui4
Suggested packages:
  qt4-qtconfig
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libqtgui4
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 56 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/3.992 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
(Reading database ... 336705 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace libqtgui4:amd64 4:4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1~ubuntu13.04~ppa1 (using .../libqtgui4_4%3a4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement libqtgui4:amd64 ...
dpkg: error processing /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtgui4_4%3a4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libqtgui4/LGPL_EXCEPTION.txt', which is different from other instances of package libqtgui4:amd64
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libqtgui4_4%3a4.8.4+dfsg-0ubuntu9.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please add to your question what happens when you do `sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: I have added it above.

Comment: The question has been answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu is telling you what to do
run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these

Then, from a command promt, type
sudo apt-get update
this will only update package manager to latest packages. After successful, you should be able to do:
sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: Thank you for a quick response! I have tried: apt-get -f install than sudo apt-get update than sudo apt-get upgrade. Still have the same issue...